# How to decode zend encoded file?

Tags: php, apache, zend-loader

I am working on one project. its purchased from

https://pintastic.com/products/Pinterest-Clone-Script-v3/open-source-license/module

Its working on https://cryyo.com/

But when i am trying to setup code at localhost its throw the error

```
Fatal error: Incompatible file format: The encoded file has format major ID 5, whereas the Loader expects 7 in /var/www/html/cryonic/Core/Base/Init.php on line 0
```

I had tried to setup this project 
on 
Ubuntu 
Mac OSX
Windows 7

But its showing me same error !

Please let me know if anyone have same issue & solved

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What version did you purchase?

Comment: Pinterest ™ Clone Script v 3.5 Modules